How can I resume from a devcontainer after closing vscode?
I am pretty newbie to devcontainer, and currently playing devconainer with vscode. My understanding is that devcontainer is just a container and vscode just connects to it, so the running container should somehow keep the status of the workspace and I can reconnect to it after I close vscode window. However, to my surprise, it does not work just like that, I have read the documentation of devcontainer for vscode but did not find an answer. So my question now is, is there a way to resume from the running container exactly like when I quit the vscode client. Below are the screenshots of one trial to resume from a simple alpine devcontainer.

New a dev container




2. The status after I launched the container

In this picture, we can see that there are files in Explorer, and the devcontainer name on the bottom-left corner is pretty meaningful. We can also find the container on Docker Desktop UI here.

I know that after I close the vscode window, by default the container will be stopped, so I modified devcontainer.json to be like this:
{
    "name": "Alpine",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:alpine-3.19",
    "shutdownAction": "none"

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "uname -a",

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    // "customizations": {},

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}

And rebuilt the docker container

3. Now I close vscode window, and we can see the container is still running

But when I try to use Attach to Running Container like this


We can see there is no file in Explorer and the devcontainer name is not so meaningful now.

Can anyone help me to understand why it works like this? And how I can achieve the goal to resume from the devcontainer that is still running after I close vscode window? Thank you!

Now with the .devcontainer.json file in the project, whenever you open the folder in Visual Studio Code, it will ask you if you want to open the project in a container.

Hi @Hackerman Thanks for your answer, actually this is also another problem. When I created the devcontainer from scratch, vscode actually created a docker volume first and put all those files in docker volume. I know I can copy those data from docker volume to my local machine, but I still wonder how I can do so with just using docker volume. Meanwhile, if attaching to the running container does not show the same status as I left it, where did it go wrong? Or what should I do to make it resume from where I left by attaching the running container?
